# Titanium.Filesystem.getFile read() (Ti sdk 5.0.0) on android returns json instead of byte stream

Tags: json, titanium, httprequest, blob, file-read

After updating to Titanium sdk 5.0.0 and xcode 7.0 i have many problems among which is this one:

I want to read local image file and send via http request to server (**the problem is with android devices, it returns json string instead byte stream**):

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
...
xhr.open("POST", Alloy.Globals.url + "api/agent/createreport");

xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Alloy.Globals.user.access_token);

xhr.setRequestHeader("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
...
params[file] = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(images[i]).read();

Ti.API.info('DATA BLOB ' + JSON.stringify(params[file]));
...
xhr.send(params);
```

**the output of Ti.API.info is :**

```
"file": {
    "hidden": false,
    "nativePath": "file:///storage/sdcard0/com.isource.polocpi/img-21c24c22-1fd0-4d51-9230-8303ced12410.jpg",
    "writable": true,
    "executable": false,
    "parent": {
      "hidden": false,

....

,
  "nativePath": "file:///storage/sdcard0/com.isource.polocpi/img-21c24c22-1fd0-4d51-9230-8303ced12410.jpg",
  "height": 600,
  "length": 47926,
  "width": 1024,
  "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
  "apiName": "Ti.Blob",
  "text": null,
  "type": 1,
  "bubbleParent": true
}
```

**before the update, with the old sdk 4.0.0 when i tried to print JSON.stringify(params[file]) it was returning just {} and not all this json string. This works fine on iphone with the old and also the new sdk but not on android.**